# Для проверки лицензии android-приложения необходимо активное интернет-соединение?

Tags: android

Вопрос может сперва звучать глупо, но почему я его задаю... Я хочу выпустить своё приложение на платной основе и полностью проштудировал всю [инструкцию](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html). 
В самом начале про разрешения, которые необходимо добавить, написано, что нужно добавить **com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE**, но там не было написано, что нужно разрешение для доступа в сеть, поэтому я резонно предположил, что это производится без наличия интернета. Возможно, я неправ, но хотелось бы перестраховаться и услышать ваше мнение по этому поводу или ваш реальный опыт.

Comment: Платный контент или само приложение платное?

Answer (score 2):

Проверка производится средствами Google Play Services, а не непосредственно вашим приложением, так что разрешения на доступ в интернет именно вашему приложению не нужно.
Google Play Services для проверки интернет конечно же использует, хоть и кеширует результаты на какое-то время. Так что ниличие интернета все же необходимо.

Comment: Эм, нет? Проверку в коде самому разработчику надо писать.

Comment: Понятно, что за вас никто код писать не будет. Я говорю, что класс LicenseChecker, через который вы проверяете валидность лицензии, напрямую в интернет не обращается. Если посмотрите его исходник, то увидите, что там происходит биндинг к глобальному сервису из состава Google Play Services, который уже выполняет махинации вне контекста вашего приложения, потом возвращая вам результат.

Answer (score 2):

Не лезет в комментарии:

У меня есть приложение, написанное специально для параноиков, приложение не имеет доступа к сети (низзя!). Так вот, приложение платное, и после покупки приложение, конечно же, должно проверить лицензию, и оно обращается к сервисам Google Play, и приложение Google Play само обращается к серверам, гугля для проверки лицензии.

Поскольку мои юзеры параноики, то у них телефоны обычно отрублены от сети и постоянно стоит вой - а зачем нужно подключение к сети! Да вы тут шпиены, да-всю-мою-инфу-слили и проч., проч. Я написал огромнейший FAQ для таких юзеров с объяснением, зачем это все нужно. Также пришлось писать некую кэширующую приладу, чтобы проверка лицензии происходила лишь раз при установке аппы и т.д.

Как-то так.

P.S. Где-то видел ссылку на статейку, где рассказывалось о методе доступа в сеть для приложений, не имеющих прямого доступа в сеть именно посредством таких сервисов. Ну, например, достаточно поставить в телефон юзера некое приложение для коннекта с неким типа аппстором, ну и можно повесить сервисочек, через который можно ходить в сеть, даже не имея пермишенов.